# Как вызвать пользовательскую функцию в PDO-запросе?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Есть функция:

```
function transliter($s){
   $s=trim(iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE", transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII', $s)));
    $s=preg_replace('/\s+/ui', '_', $s);
    $s=preg_replace('/[^\w-]/ui', '', $s);
    return mb_strtolower($s, 'utf-8');
}
```

И есть вызов PDO:

```
$upd=$dbh->query("UPDATE `posts` SET `url_t`={transliter(head)} WHERE `id`=161");
```

To есть, мне нужно брать значение поля 'head' обрабатывать его функцией и записывать в поле 'url_t'.

Как это сделать?

Comment: так не выйдет. единственный способ: делаете обычный цикл чтения поля запросом select и внутри цикла даете update каждой строки. Либо сделать то же самое с использованием функций mysql https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-replace-function.php (в MySQL 8.0 доступны так же функции работы с регулярными выражениями)

Comment: Верю Вам безоговорочно. Спасибо.

Comment: Вообще все зависит от вашей базы данных, не многие знают, а те кто знает чаще не использует, но большинство реляционных баз данных умеют не только запросы выполнять но и хранить пользовательские функции, процедуры. Если такую функцию написать нативно допустим в mysql то вполне себе можно обойтись и без разворачивания массива

Comment: Спасибо, но transliterator_transliterate, например, требует для себя отдельной php-библиотеки. Так что вопрос можно считать закрытым.